# Add </tr><tr> via jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table, row, tablerow

I have a problem and I have no idea how to solve it:

I have a table:

---

### | A | B |

### | D | C |

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
A
</td>
<td>
B
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
C
</td>
<td>
D
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And now I need to add `</tr><tr>` after each odd td. Result should be one column table:

---

### | A |

### | B |

### | C |

### | D |

I was already trying to make this work with jQuery `$("#table tr > td:nth-child(odd)").after("</tr><tr>");`, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery
By the way, the jQuery code isn't working since the table has no ID, but the jQuery code reffers to #table

Comment: `</tr><tr>` does not look like valid HTML which can be parsed to DOM. Keep in mind: jQuery works with DOM elements, not HTML.

Comment: The reason I am doing it, I want this table to be responsive to screen width. So I want each cell to appear below previous when screen is less then ...px

Comment: you can manipulate the `display` property of elements to achieve that. This way can avoid extensive and expensive DOM manipulation.

Comment: You mean I can `display:none` each even cell? This doesn't suit. If you mean something else, can you give me a hint? Brains are melting, so I am slow on understanding now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (http://jsfiddle.net/b5S3U/4/)

```
var cols = 1;
$('tr').each(function () {
    var after = $(this);
    while ($(this).children().length > cols) {
        after = $('<tr>').insertAfter(after).append($('>:gt(' + (cols - 1) + '):lt(' + (cols) + ')', this));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('table td:odd').each(function(i, v){
    var $this = $(this);
    var parent = $this.parent();
    $this.detach().wrap('<tr></tr>').insertAfter(parent)
})
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jDWmL/)